# Jenkins file permissions of checked out files

Tags: svn, jenkins, permissions, umask

I use the Subversion plugin for checking out.

Checked out files are getting the permissions 750 (rwxr-x---).

Can I change this somewhere?

Thank you very much.

whosit

Edit:
My system's umask is set to 0022.

Comment: What is your umask set to?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

This fixed it: http://neeohw.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/jenkins-change-umask/

I had to add the right umask to /etc/default/jenkins.